# How to check if slice interface elements have the same dynamic type?

Tags: go, reflection, interface, slice

I have the following structs and they follow this structure:

`A` is the interface, and `B`, `C`, `D` are all types with interface `A`.

I have a slice of variables `args` all with type with interface `A`, each of which can be `B`, `C`, `D` type specifically.

I'd like to write a for loop to judge if all variables in the slice fall into the same dynamic type.

I wrote the following code:

```golang
var existingTyp A
for i, d := range args {
 switch typ := d.(type) {
   case *B, *C, *D:
    if existingTyp == nil {
        existingTyp = typ
    } else {
        if typ != existingTyp {
            panic("error!")
        }
   }
}
```

How to revise the code to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the equality operator `==` on the interface values. Even if the dynamic types are the same, the comparison may return false if they have fields with different values. Or it panics if `B`, `C` and `D` aren't comparable to begin with.

Instead you can use reflection and use `==` on `reflect.Type`. This solution doesn't require you to update the code if you add more types that implement `A`.

```
func dynamicTypesEq(args []A) bool {
    var a reflect.Type
    for _, d := range args {
        t := reflect.TypeOf(d)
        if a == nil {
            a = t
            continue
        }
        if a != t {
            return false
        }

    }
    return true
}
```

Calling the function with some example slices:

```
func main() {
    a := []A{&B{}, &B{}, &B{}}
    fmt.Println(dynamicTypesEq(a)) // true

    b := []A{&C{}, &B{}, &B{}}
    fmt.Println(dynamicTypesEq(b)) // false


    c := []A{&D{}, &D{}, &B{}}
    fmt.Println(dynamicTypesEq(c)) // false
}
```

Note that this function reports false in case the input has `*B` and `B`. Clearly, a pointer type is not the same as the base type.

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/QOCvSyxGPRU

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it using the reflect package. If type of some element is different from the type of the first element, then the slice contains mixed value types.

```
func check(args []interface{}) bool {
    if len(args) == 0 {
        return true
    }
    t := reflect.TypeOf(args[0])
    for _, v := range args[1:] {
        if reflect.TypeOf(v) != t {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Here's how to do it without reflect. Keep a state variable that records the last type seen. If the current type is not the last type, then the slice contains mixed value types.

```
func check(args []interface{}) bool {
    const (
        initState = iota
        typeB
        typeC
        typeD
    )
    state := initState
    for _, d := range args {
        switch d.(type) {
        case *B:
            if state != initState && state != typeB {
                return false
            }
            state = typeB
        case *C:
            if state != initState && state != typeC {
                return false
            }
            state = typeC
        case *D:
            if state != initState && state != typeD {
                return false
            }
            state = typeD
        default:
            panic("unsupported type")
        }
    }
    return true
}
```